# fill new column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of dim (5004346 x 14). I am trying to add a new column (`Risk_level`) based if values in one column (`iter`) match the values in different lists.

I have:

```
def assign_risk(df):
    if  df['iter'].isin(no):
        val = 'no_risk'
    elif  df['iter'].isin(low):
        val = 'low_risk'
    elif  df['iter'].isin(med):
        val = 'med_risk'
    else:
        val = 'high_risk'
    return val

# create new column with risk attribute
df['Risk_level'] = df.apply(assign_risk, axis=1)
df
```

But i'm getting the error `'str' object has no attribute 'isin'`.

A kind of mwe:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'iter' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]})
temp2 = [1,2]
temp3 = [3]
temp4 = [4]

def test_temp(df):
    if  df['iter'].isin(temp2):
        val = 'no_risk'
    elif  df['iter'].isin(temp3):
        val = 'low_risk'
    else:
        val = 'high_risk'
    return val

temp['test'] = temp.apply(test_temp, axis=1)
temp
```

Also returns `'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'isin'`

Why isn't this working?? i've been trying for hours and don't understand....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['iter']` in `apply` is a scalar value, personally speaking I would name it as `row['iter']`, you need change `isin` to `in`

```py
def test_temp(df):
    if  df['iter'] in temp2:
        val = 'no_risk'
    elif  df['iter'] in temp3:
        val = 'low_risk'
    else:
        val = 'high_risk'
    return val
```

You can use `np.select` instead

```py
temp['test_where'] = np.select(
    [temp['iter'].isin(temp2),
     temp['iter'].isin(temp3),],
    ['no_risk', 'low_risk'],
    'high_risk'
)
```

Comment: i tried `df['Risk_level'] = np.select(
    [df['iter'].isin(norisk['iter'].unique()),
    df['iter'].isin(lowrisk['iter'].unique()),
    df['iter'].isin(medrisk['iter'].unique()),],
    ['no_risk', 'low_risk', 'med_risk'], 'high_risk')` because it's much faster.. but when i check `df['Risk_level'].unique()` it only assigned `high_risk`. I don't understand why

Comment: @kas How about `.unique().tolist()`?

Comment: yeah, i have `no = norisk['iter'].unique().tolist()
low = lowrisk['iter'].unique().tolist()
med = medrisk['iter'].unique().tolist()
hi = highrisk['iter'].unique().tolist()` originally, but it returns the same problem (ie only attributes 'High risk')

Comment: i'm trying with the function and apply... but it's taking a reallllyyyy long time, given the size of my df.... ideally np.select() works, but i don't understand why it isn't actually assigning the proper category

Comment: @kas `np.select([cond1, cond2], [val1, val2], default)` works like if `cond1` is True, it chooses `val1` elif `cond2` is True, it chooses `val2`. If none is True, it chooses the default value. You can check if each `condx` is your desired output.

Comment: indeed, i figured out where the problem is (comparing str to int). it works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` or `map`

```
temp['iter'].replace({
    1: "no_risk",
    2: "no_risk",
    3: "low_risk",
    4: "high_risk"
})
```

or if you want to use the lists as dict keys, then convert them to tuples, though I personally think this is less pythonic

```
temp['iter'].replace({
    tuple(temp2): "no_risk",
    tuple(temp3):  "low_risk",
    tuple(temp4): "high_risk"
})
```

You can also use `numpy`'s `where

```
import numpy as np 
np.where(temp["iter"].isin(temp2), "no_risk",
 np.where(temp["iter"].isin(temp3), "low_risk", "high_risk")
```

Why does `isin` fail?

`isin` returns an array with several booleans (a mix of T/F) which will be ambiguous for a boolean check.